# Group by in CQL for Cassandra DB not working

Tags: cassandra

I have this table in a Cassandra keyspace:

```
create table hashtags(
id uuid,
text text,
frequence int,
primary key ((text), frequence, id))
with clustering order by (frequence desc, id asc);
```

So I have `text` as partition key and `frequence, id` as clustering key.
According to [Cassandra documentation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10707) regarding the support for `GROUP BY` operations, I should be able to run this sort of query:

```
select text, sum(frequence) from hashtags 
group by text;
```

But I keep getting this error:

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 2:0 no viable alternative at input 'group' (...text, sum(frequence) from [hashtags] group...)

Is there something I misunderstood from the guide? How can I run correctly this query?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Which cassandra version are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me on Apache Cassandra 3.10. I tried from cqlsh.

```html
cqlsh:test> select * from hashtags ;

 text  | frequence | id
-------+-----------+--------------------------------------
 hello |         5 | 07ef8ee4-6492-4112-babb-fc3ac2893701
 hello |         4 | 3f6f3b1d-4a33-4a07-ad60-2274a9dc5577
 hello |         1 | 4adf7e2a-f3b9-41eb-85cf-f4c4bdc5d322
    hi |         7 | 71718f46-455e-4012-a306-f31f1cb2454a

(4 rows)
cqlsh:test> select text, sum(frequence) from hashtags group by text;

 text  | system.sum(frequence)
-------+-----------------------
 hello |                    10
    hi |                     7

(2 rows)

Warnings :
Aggregation query used without partition key
```

Comment: So I guess I'm not using the latest version. Thank you for testing it, I was not so wrong after all.

Comment: Not working in Cassandra 3.11 see my query - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003345/cassandra-cql-3-11-how-to-use-group-by