# Cassandra CQL 3.11 - How to use group by?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

How to use **group by** clause in Cassandra 3.11 ? I followed this link - [Group by in CQL for Cassandra DB not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603610/group-by-in-cql-for-cassandra-db-not-working)

although the answer is accepted but when I created the same table and run the query , it is showing different result (not as expected)

the steps I followed are -

```
create table hashtags(
id uuid,
texts text,
frequence int,
primary key ((texts), frequence, id))
with clustering order by (frequence desc, id asc);
```

then inserted some dummy data -

[image]
after that run following query -

```
select texts, sum(frequence) from hashtags group by texts;
```

and the output is -

[image]

**Expected output -**

```
 text  | system.sum(frequence)
-------+-----------------------
 hello |                    10
    hi |                     7
```

Comment: Your query seems fine. Can you confirm the version of CQL being used here? I tested with Cassandra 3.11.4 and it works for me.

Comment: @elixir - I have the same version - 3.11.4 but the above codes are not working for me. Is there anything else I need to check?

Comment: Did you check if that version is compatible with your workbench. Did you try the same query using `cqlsh`? If it works, it could be due to missing updates on Workbench.

Comment: @elixir - I am newbie in Cassandra, can you please let me know how to check it?

Comment: @elixir - thanks for your comment, it helped me to find out the bug. I was using Visual Studio Code to run and test the query. However the same query is working fine in cqlsh.

Comment: Missed your earlier comment. Glad it worked.

Comment: @elixir Can you please help me with the o/p of `cqlsh> show version`? I have downloaded apache cassandra 3.11.4, but when I start the server and cqlsh, I see the server version being `3.7.0`. Want to understand what am I missing please?

Comment: @Divs Can you paste the output of `show version` command.

Comment: @elixir posted in details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241570/cassandra-3-11-4-cql-group-by-not-working